# Which query protocol does Wso2 Identity Server use to communicate with PostgreSQL Database?

Tags: database, postgresql, wso2, protocols, wso2-identity-server

I need to know which "query protocol" Wso2 Identity Server is using to connect with PostgreSQL Database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say  postgrsql line protocol via JDBC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 is using Postgress JDBC Driver to connect to Postgress Database, hence does not explicitly handle connections. As per the Postgres [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html), the following is the default protocol that's being used.

```
The driver supports the V3 frontend/backend protocols. The V3 protocol was introduced in 7.4 and the driver will by default try to connect using the V3 protocol.
```

Also, it seems you can set the protocol version as a JDBC connection property as well. So you should be able to change this by adding this to Datasource configurations.